# 'Have a possibility' vs. 'have the possibility'

Tags: articles

When trying to say a sentence with the following structure:

> You also have [x] possibility to open a savings account

When is it appropriate to use 'a' and when is it appropriate to use 'the'?

Comment: I'd say they're equivalent, and that it is unprofitable to try to decide best usage on logical grounds (is the possibility best considered as a specific or non-specific case here). Both variants are used, but [these Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have+a+possibility+to%2Chave+the+possibility+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chave%20a%20possibility%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chave%20the%20possibility%20to%3B%2Cc0) show the usual choice (the).

Answer (score 2):

### a possibility

a/an = indefinite article ("A" and "an" signal that the noun modified is indefinite, referring to any member of a group)

> You also have a possibility to open a savings account.

This statement is suggestive of one possibility out of a few other possibilities.

### the possibility

the = definite article *(The definite article is used before singular and plural nouns when the noun is specific or particular.)*

> You also have the possibility to open a savings account

Here, more stress is laid on the single possibility, without any consideration for other possibilities (which *may/may not* exist). *The possibility of opening a saving account* has much more weight in this statement, as compared to the latter.

Comment: I disagree.  The example refers to a single option.  Even if "possibility" referred to some non-count measure, there is only a single value associated with the option.  Only "the" would be applicable.  That said, "to open" doesn't go with possibility.  You could say "it is **possible to** open..." or "the **possibility of** opening...".  "possible to open" would be the more natural way to say it, but typical speech would be "you **can** open..." (one syllable to replace the equivalent "have the possibility to").